# Not able to send checkbox data from all pagination in datatable from template to view in django

Tags: python, jquery, django, datatable, django-views

I have a datatable in my django template in which there is a checkbox next to every row to send the row data to a view function to make some mass updations in django model. But problem is if the multiple rows are on the same page in pagination then i can send the data accurately BUT if i select row 2 from page 1 and row 5 from page 3 only the row value from page 3 will be sent to the view function.!

TEMPLATE.HTML

```
{% block jquery %}
<script type="text/javascript" class="init">
    $(document).ready( function ($) {
        var $submit = $("#updiv").hide(),
            $cbs = $('input[name="updelegate"]').click(function() {
                $submit.toggle( $cbs.is(":checked") );
            });
       $('#myTable').DataTable({
            dom: 'lBfrtip',
            "pageLength": 1,
            "language": {
              "emptyTable": "No Delegates Available",
              "sSearch": "Search Delegates: ",
              "info": " Showing _START_-_END_ out of Total _TOTAL_ Delegates",

            }
        });
    });



</script>
{% endblock %}
<form id="myForm" action="{% url 'mass-delegates' %}" method="POST">
                        {% csrf_token %}
                        <table id="myTable" class="table table-striped table-bordered" style="width:100%">
                            <thead class="thead-dark">
                            <tr>
                                <th></th>
                                <th scope="col">#</th>
                                <th scope="col">Name</th>
                                <th scope="col">Email</th>
                                <th scope="col">Phone</th>
                                <th scope="col">Company</th>
                                <th scope="col">Designation</th>
                                <th scope="col">Address</th>
                                <th scope="col">City</th>
                                <th></th>
                                <th></th>
                            </tr>
                            </thead>
                            <tbody>
                            {% for del in delegates %}
                            <tr>
                                <td>
                                    <label class="container">
                                        <input type="checkbox" id="updelegate" name="updelegate"
                                               value="{{ del.id }}">
                                        <span class="checkmark"></span>
                                    </label>
                                </td>
                                <td>{{ del.id }}</td>
                                <td>{{ del.first_name }} {{ del.last_name }}</td>
                                <td>{{ del.email }}</td>
                                <td>{{ del.phone }}</td>
                                <td>{{ del.company }}</td>
                                <td>{{ del.designation }}</td>
                                <td>{{ del.address }}</td>
                                <td>{{ del.city }} ({{ del.pincode }})</td>
                                <td>
                                    <a href="{% url 'delegate' dataset_id=del.dataset_id %}">View</a>
                                </td>
                                <td>
                                    <a href="{% url 'edit-delegate' id=del.id %}">Edit</a>
                                </td>
                            </tr>
                            {% endfor %}
                            </tbody>
                        </table>
                        <div id="updiv">
                            <select name="eventid">
                                {% for ev in events %}
                                <option value="{{ ev.id }}">{{ ev.name }}</option>
                                {% endfor %}
                            </select>
                            <input type="submit" onclick="return confirm('Confirm Adding to Event?');" class="upbtn"
                                   name="update" value="Add to Event"/>
                        </div>
                    </form>
```

VIEW.PY

```
def mass_delegates(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        toupdate = request.POST.getlist('updelegate')
        eventid = request.POST.get('eventid')
        array_length = len(toupdate)
        for i in range(array_length):
            if not EventDelegate.objects.filter(event_id=eventid, delegate_id=toupdate[i]).exists():
                EventDelegate.objects.create(event_id=eventid, delegate_id=toupdate[i])

        return event_det(request, eventid)
```

Comment: If you use checkboxes in the rows, the Datatable just forgets selected attributes when page is changed.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of using the checkboxes, you can directly use the **select attribute** in the Datatables api. Check [Select Rows in Datatables](https://datatables.net/extensions/select/examples/api/get.html)

Moreover, Since you want to select multiple rows at once, you might consider checking [Multi Select rows in Datatables](https://datatables.net/examples/api/select_row.html) out

You can add the id in the 0th column, then

```
dataTable = $(.selector).Datatable() 

dataTable.columns([0]).visible(false);
```

You can hide the column like that and then when you send your request, you still have your id

Comment: but your solution is not providing me that how will i send the id against each row to my view method

Comment: You can add a column in your datatable that contains the data you want to send, (in this case id), and hide that column when you render your table

Comment: I have updated my answer, you can also use your hidden fields to filter or highlight or anythin